# If image is not available, skip to the next one

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I have an Android app that displays pictures loaded from an HTTP request in a GridView using Glide.

What I want to do: on the server let's say I have -> picture.jpg and picture.png
Since I won't know for sure what image I have available, the JPG, or PNG I pass a string array containing "/server/picture.jpg" and "/server/picture.png".

When I try to use

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(images[position]).centerCrop().into(imageView)
```

I want Glide to skip the unavailable picture and not to create a Grid element.

Basically, if picture in URL is 404, skip, and load the next one.
How can I do this?

Comment: Just guessing maybe to loop through all your array or List of images and hide those are empty or delete them.

Comment: None of the items in the array are empty, all of them contain a link. However, that link may be 404 because of the wrong image extension